# How can I redirect the Clicked Notification to another page in React Native?

Tags: react-native, notifications

I'm trying to develop a project with React Native. I want to go to the Detail page that I created when I click the notification on the home screen. but it keeps throwing me on the first page. How can I do this?

I installed this package [Push Notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

**Local Notification**

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    
      title: Hello ,
      message: World,
      channelId:"Example",          
    });
```

I put the configure structure in index.js

**index.js**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {Detail} from "./src/pages"

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('TOKEN:', token);
      },
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
        
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
               <Stack.Navigator>
                   <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
               </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
           );
        
      },
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },
    
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there are 2 problems.
1- Your "onNotification", should not return a navigation container, since it isn't what you want... you just want to redirect the user to another page.

2-  Also, you should run PushNotification configuration, inside a react component, you are handle with navigation wrong, if you're using react-navigation 5.x, you should try navigate with hooks, something like

```
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

    
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    
        PushNotification.configure({
          onRegister: function (token) {
            console.log('TOKEN:', token);
          },
          onNotification: function (notification) {
            console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
            
             navigation.navigate("Details")
            
          },
          permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          },
        
          popInitialNotification: true,
          requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',
        });
```

If you have issues handle with navigation, it can help you  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/